# Erro na leitura de uma string em arquivo

Tags: c

Bom estou lendo um arquivo com a formatação do tipo:

nome.txt nomes colunas tipos colunas

Onde estou conseguindo ler todas essas strings, porém na hora de imprimi-las, por exemplo em uma uma linha com dois nomes de colunas e seus respectivos dois tipos, o printf só mostras as duas primeiras strings e em  sequência printa dois nulls. Segue o código:

```
char **tipos_coluna; 
tipos_coluna = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(2*qtd_colunas)); //Matriz de strings alocada dinamicamente
for (int i = 0; i < qtd_colunas; ++i)
{
    tipos_coluna[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
}

FILE *colunas_tabelas = fopen("colunas_tabelas/colunas_tabelas.txt", "r");

char validar[50];
while((fscanf(colunas_tabelas, "%s\n", validar)) != EOF)
{
    if( !(strcmp(validar,tabela_url)) )
    {   
        int i=0; 
        while((fscanf(colunas_tabelas, " %s", tipos_coluna[i])) != EOF)
        {

            if(i == (2*qtd_colunas)-1){
                break;
            }

            ++i; 
        }
    }
}

fclose(colunas_tabelas);


for (int i = 0; i < 2*qtd_colunas; ++i)
{
    printf("%s ", tipos_coluna[i]);
}
    printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while((fscanf(colunas_tabelas, "%s\n", validar)) != EOF)
```

Tem dois erros, neste trecho há uma inconsistência, pois o fscanf não retorna EOF. Resolvi pegando a linha com fgets e formatando-a com sscanf.

Já o segundo, é que não estou alocando a quantidade correta de linhas

```
for (int i = 0; i < qtd_colunas; ++i)
```

Que seria

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2*qtd_colunas; ++i)
```